# amplify gen2 sandbox with existing stack

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

With command:

npx amplify generate config --app-id  --branch  --format json --out-dir config

It correctly generate amplifyconfiguration.json file in config folders with correct IDs in it that correspond to  already deployed stack.

But then with command:

npx amplify sandbox --config-out-dir ./config --format json

It don't care about whatever options I've tried and every time re-generate a complete fresh new stack with a new amplifyconfiguration.json file in project's root folder.

This is not what I want.

What I'd like is a sandbox that use backend stack from an already deployed branch (with seed data).

Answer (score 0):

use:

npx amplify sandbox **--out-dir** ./config --format json

and **not**:

npx amplify sandbox **--config-out-dir** ./config --format json like explained in official doc: - [Generate client config](https://docs.amplify.aws/gen2/deploy-and-host/sandbox-environments/features/#generate-client-config)